# Servlet server 404 error in windows but not linux

Tags: spring, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I created a Java Servlet server running on Tomcat 7.0 through eclipse. The Project uses Maven and Spring. The project works perfectly on Linux (Mint) but not on Windows. I am able to get into .jsp pages but not able to access servlets because I get a 404 error(only on Winosws).

So if I look up `http://localhost:8080/projectName/index.jsp` this will work. But `http://localhost:8080/projectName/ServletName` I get a 404 error, the servlet is suppose to redirects to a .jsp page.

My `web.xml` file

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">   
  <display-name>projectName</display-name>  
    <context-param>
        <param-name>ApplicationContext</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
     </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>projectName</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <description>
        </description>
        <display-name>WebService</display-name>
        <servlet-name>WebService</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.servlet.WebService</servlet-class>
    </servlet>      

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>projectName</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>WebService</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/WebService</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>    

    <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>    
</web-app>
```

Comment: Per your web.xml, are you trying to call WebService servlet by putting /WebService in the url?

Comment: Eclipse generates the `<servlet>` and `<servlet-mapping>` tags automatically when I create a new servlet. I did try to modify it to `<url-pattern>projectName/WebService</url-pattern>` but same error happens

Comment: So you're not using the same Tomcat version in both environments?

Comment: Both use Tomcat 7.0

Comment: Can you deploy your webapp through eclipse in tomcat (Run As -> Run On Server) and then check the url which it creates, may be projectName is different when you are deploying...... then use that url and then append your servlet name to it. Let us know if it helps...

Comment: That is what I am doing, works great in linux. In windows when I do the same thing same URL open `localhost:8080/projectName` but when I try to access a servlet so example `localhost:8080/projectName/servlet` it wont work on windows but will work on linux.

Comment: If you are starting a new project, might I suggest using Tomcat 8.5 instead of 7.0?

Comment: What does the WebServlet actually do? Does it, for example, forward to a JSP when it's done processing?